# Django "Installed Apps" sync issue

Tags: python, django

I have the following Django directory structure:

```
PROJECT_FOLDER
\__ manage.py
\__ MY_PROJECT
    \__ __init__.py
    \__ settings.py
    \__ urls.py
    \__ wsgi.py
    \__ APPS
        \__ MY_APP
            \__ __init.py
            \__ admin.py
            \__ models.py
            \__ views.py
            \__ tests.py
```

In settings.py I included my app in the follwing line:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...

    # Applications
    'MY_PROJECT.APPS.MY_APP'
)
```

But when I do **syncdb** (python manage.py syncdb), it gives me an error:

```
ImportError: No module named APPS.MY_APP
```

In the INSTALLED_APPS, I tried different lines like:

```
'PROJECT_FOLDER.MY_PROJECT.APPS.MY_APP',
'APPS.MY_APP'
```

but all of these give me errors...

Is there anything wrong with my settings.py or directory structure???

tHanks

Comment: Usually an app is in its own folder in the project folder. Thus at same level as my_project you would have my_app. Then 'my_app' would register in installed apps.

Answer (score 2):

You can check a few things here:

- If `PROJECT_FOLDER` is in `PYTHONPATH`.
- Create an empty `__init__.py` file in `APPS` folder.
- The `__init__.py` file in `MY_APP` is named incorrectly.